# Microsoft charting stacked area still visible even when y-values are all 0

Tags: charts

Here is my problem. Let's say I have 2 stacked area series and their data looks like this :

Series A (Color blue) :
X values {1, 2, 3, 4}
Y values {4, 6, 7, 6}

Series B (Color red) :
X values {1, 2, 3, 4}
Y values {0, 0, 0, 0}

If I had these 2 series to a chart (A first and B second), there is still a red line that appears on top of the blue area even if all the y-values of the B series are 0. Is there a way to make sure that the red line doesn't appear in the graph without removing the B-series from the legend?

Answer (score 0):

Format the data series to have a fill only and no border. If the areas have a border, it will show even if the values are 0.

Comment: How do you format the data series to have a fill only? I don't see the  any property related the that in the Series class.

Comment: Might help if you specified what product you're working with. My suggestion works fine with charts created in MS Office.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Charting for .NET